# Font-Awesome Icons not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I am using bootstrap in my application to create a navbar. It works great, except when I start adding icons to my dropdown menu which uses font-awesome.

It works in Firefox perfectly but it also needs to work in IE8. I search stackoverflow for other solutions and none of them seemed to work in my case.

Here is what I get when I load my page:

[image]

Any help on how to fix this would be great!

**Here is the Font-awesome.css file**

```
    * -------------------------- */
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('../../bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../../bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
}
/* FONT AWESOME CORE
 * -------------------------- */
[class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  *margin-right: .3em;
}
[class^="icon-"]:before,
[class*=" icon-"]:before {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  display: inline-block;
  speak: none;
}
/* makes the font 33% larger relative to the icon container */
.icon-large:before {
  vertical-align: -10%;
  font-size: 1.3333333333333333em;
}
/* makes sure icons active on rollover in links */
a [class^="icon-"],
a [class*=" icon-"],
a [class^="icon-"]:before,
a [class*=" icon-"]:before {
  display: inline;
}
/* increased font size for icon-large */
[class^="icon-"].icon-fixed-width,
[class*=" icon-"].icon-fixed-width {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.2857142857142858em;
  text-align: center;
}
[class^="icon-"].icon-fixed-width.icon-large,
[class*=" icon-"].icon-fixed-width.icon-large {
  width: 1.5714285714285714em;
}
ul.icons-ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-indent: -0.7142857142857143em;
  margin-left: 2.142857142857143em;
}
ul.icons-ul > li .icon-li {
  width: 0.7142857142857143em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
[class^="icon-"].hide,
[class*=" icon-"].hide {
  display: none;
}
.icon-muted {
  color: #eeeeee;
}
.icon-light {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.icon-dark {
  color: #333333;
}
.icon-border {
  border: solid 1px #eeeeee;
  padding: .2em .25em .15em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.icon-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.icon-2x.icon-border {
  border-width: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.icon-3x {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.icon-3x.icon-border {
  border-width: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.icon-4x {
  font-size: 4em;
}
.icon-4x.icon-border {
  border-width: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.icon-5x {
  font-size: 5em;
}
.icon-5x.icon-border {
  border-width: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
.pull-left {
  float: left;
}
[class^="icon-"].pull-left,
[class*=" icon-"].pull-left {
  margin-right: .3em;
}
[class^="icon-"].pull-right,
[class*=" icon-"].pull-right {
  margin-left: .3em;
}
/* BOOTSTRAP SPECIFIC CLASSES
 * -------------------------- */
/* Bootstrap 2.0 sprites.less reset */
html > body [class^="icon-"],
[class*=" icon-"] {
  display: inline;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background-image: none;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  margin-top: 0;
}
/* more sprites.less reset */
.icon-white,
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.nav-pills > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.nav-list > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.nav-list > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.navbar-inverse .nav > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-menu > .active > a > [class*=" icon-"],
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class^="icon-"],
.dropdown-submenu:hover > a > [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: none;
}
/* keeps Bootstrap styles with and without icons the same */
.btn [class^="icon-"].icon-large,
.nav [class^="icon-"].icon-large,
.btn [class*=" icon-"].icon-large,
.nav [class*=" icon-"].icon-large {
  line-height: .9em;
}
.btn [class^="icon-"].icon-spin,
.nav [class^="icon-"].icon-spin,
.btn [class*=" icon-"].icon-spin,
.nav [class*=" icon-"].icon-spin {
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav-tabs [class^="icon-"],
.nav-pills [class^="icon-"],
.nav-tabs [class*=" icon-"],
.nav-pills [class*=" icon-"],
.nav-tabs [class^="icon-"].icon-large,
.nav-pills [class^="icon-"].icon-large,
.nav-tabs [class*=" icon-"].icon-large,
.nav-pills [class*=" icon-"].icon-large {
  line-height: .9em;
}
.btn [class^="icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn [class*=" icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn [class^="icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x,
.btn [class*=" icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x {
  margin-top: .18em;
}
.btn [class^="icon-"].icon-spin.icon-large,
.btn [class*=" icon-"].icon-spin.icon-large {
  line-height: .8em;
}
.btn.btn-small [class^="icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-small [class*=" icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-small [class^="icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-small [class*=" icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x {
  margin-top: .25em;
}
.btn.btn-large [class^="icon-"],
.btn.btn-large [class*=" icon-"] {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.btn.btn-large [class^="icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-large [class*=" icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-large [class^="icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-large [class*=" icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x {
  margin-top: .05em;
}
.btn.btn-large [class^="icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-large [class*=" icon-"].pull-left.icon-2x {
  margin-right: .2em;
}
.btn.btn-large [class^="icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x,
.btn.btn-large [class*=" icon-"].pull-right.icon-2x {
  margin-left: .2em;
}
/* EXTRAS
 * -------------------------- */
/* Stacked and layered icon */
.icon-stack {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
  vertical-align: -35%;
}
.icon-stack [class^="icon-"],
.icon-stack [class*=" icon-"] {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: inherit;
  *line-height: 2em;
}
.icon-stack .icon-stack-base {
  font-size: 2em;
  *line-height: 1em;
}
/* Animated rotating icon */
.icon-spin {
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
  animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(359deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        transform: rotate(359deg);
    }
}
/* Icon rotations and mirroring */
.icon-rotate-90:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1);
}
.icon-rotate-180:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=2);
}
.icon-rotate-270:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
.icon-flip-horizontal:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
}
.icon-flip-vertical:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
```

Comment: Try `html5shim` at `[if lt IE 9]` but download the latest release

Comment: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/2324

Comment: Are you sure you've got IE8 in IE8 rendering mode?

Comment: @Pointy, how can I place in IE8 rendering mode?

Comment: ok I used '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />' after my head tag and still same result

Comment: You can tell if it's in the wrong mode by opening up the developer tools. It tells you in the top menu of the tools window. I was just offering a suggestion; that may not be the problem. Because IE8 had weird bugs parsing @font-face declarations, there are various things that can make it not work. It might help if you'd post the CSS you're using.

Comment: @Pointy, I added the css. I also checked the link that Derek posted but the fix did not work in my case.

Comment: [Uh, here is my solution?](http://theie8countdown.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Mmm try html5.js after the main.css. This works for me.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```